# How do I make a button in tkinter that allows me to count the number of times it has been pressed?

Tags: python, tkinter

I've been trying to create a button in tkinter that tracks the amount of times hat it has been clicked but it shows me a syntax error every time I click it.

The way I intend it to work is for it to add one to the counter every time the top button is clicked, and then upon clicking the bottom one, the programme will close and the amount of times the top button has been clicked will be printed.

```
from tkinter import *

count = 0
def counter():
    count = count + 1
def total():
    print(count)
    exit ()

window = Tk()
window.geometry("175x105")
window.resizable(0, 0)

text=Label(window, text="Click the button.", font=("Times New Roman", 10))
text.pack(padx=3, pady=3)

button=Button(window, text="CLICK HERE", width=12, bg="gray", command=counter)
button.pack(padx=2, pady=2)
button2=Button(window, text="FINISH", width=12, bg="gray", command=total)
button2.pack(padx=2, pady=2)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Your code looks basically OK, except you need to add a `global count` statement to the beginning of the `counter()` function.

Comment: Asterisk/`*` imports are discouraged.

Comment: Read up on [scopes-and-namespaces](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#scopes-and-namespaces-example)

Answer (score 0):

You only have to globalize the variable `count` inside the `counter()` function. It will update the value of count every time the function is called.

Like this:

```
import tkinter as tk

count = 0


def counter():
    global count
    count = count + 1   # you can also use: count += 1


def total():
    print(count)
    exit()


window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry("175x105")
window.resizable(0, 0)

text = tk.Label(window, text="Click the button.", font=("Times New Roman", 10))
text.pack(padx=3, pady=3)

button = tk.Button(window, text="CLICK HERE", width=12, bg="gray", command=counter)
button.pack(padx=2, pady=2)
button2 = tk.Button(window, text="FINISH", width=12, bg="gray", command=total)
button2.pack(padx=2, pady=2)

window.mainloop()
```